# Retrieve field values to Django Admin using many to many relationships

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a simple task: I need to expose player name related to Game in game list (Django Admin). Game object has ManyToMany relationship with Player object via 'players' attribute. The problem is that now I have empty 'players_list' field (empty list means I don't know what to do and just leave it here[enter image description here][1]), though I tried Player.objects.all() and obviously got  all players even those who are not bound to particular game.
I feel it has simple solution but my brain refuses to work after 55 opened tabs.
Thanks in advance!
This is my models.py

```
from django.db import model 
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=54, default="")
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=54)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, default="")
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Player, blank=True, related_name='player_games')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    players_list = []
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Game, Player


class PlayerInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Game.players.through

@admin.register(Player)
class Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    search_fields = ['name', 'email']
    list_display = ('name', 'email', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
    inlines = [
    PlayerInline,
]

@admin.register(Game)
class AdminAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name',  'created_at', 'updated_at', 'players_list')
    inlines = [
    PlayerInline,
]
    exclude = ('players',)
```

Pic as it looks now
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVJ5y.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach here will be creating custom method in your model instead of single variable. You will not even have to change your [list_display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display):

```
class Game(models.Model):
    ...
    def players_list(self):
        return self.players.all()
```

Alternatively, if you want only names of players or anything else from, you can change it  (or add another method) to something like that:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    ...
    def players_list(self):
        return [player for player in self.players.all()]
        # or
        return [player.name for player in self.players.all()]
```

This is called [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp), if you are not familiar with it.

Comment: BigThanx @NixonSparrow but this option I've already used. It appeared that I can't use all() method with players attribute because "AttributeError: 'ManyToManyField' object has no attribute 'all' "

Comment: @gusygusy of course it has. You had to used it directly on class field instead of object or something similar. Please share it in your question, I'll try to help.

Comment: You are genius @NixonSparrow! Works perfectly now! I have no sufficient reputation to up your  answer yet. Thank you!